# AngularJS SSO security?

Tags: security, spring-mvc, angularjs, single-sign-on, token

We got an Angular application and we got another Spring application. The login is managed by Spring and when the user is logged, Spring redirects to the Angular app. When Spring redirects, it puts an authentication token to the header.

How to get this token with Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since AngularJS is javascript, you can echo that token in your HTML somewhere. It's a one time redirection to your angularApp. I did this on

`<meta name="csrf-token" value="xxxx-xxx" />`

And to send http calls back to your Spring App from Angular, I believe you have to send that token (e.g X-Token) in header too which can be done like

```
window.ngApp = angular.module('ngApp',[]);

ngApp.config(["$httpProvider", function(provider) {     
      provider.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
}]);
```

So everytime a http request is made, the X-Token will be part of your request.

Comment: Ok but this token is not a csrf token is an authentication token. And echo this token in HTML it's like echo the user password ... I'm not sure that it's really secure. Do you see ?

Comment: I've done it with a cookie :) ! The server send a cookie i get it on client-side and it works like a charm ! Thx

Comment: In my case CSRF token was needed as a cross signature and API call needed an API key too. But isn't Auth Token encrypted ? If javascript can read the cookie, isn't it almost like echoing that in html ? I mean people will see the cookie in inspector, right?

Comment: Of course the token is encrytped. But an auth token and a csrf token are different put a csrf token in a meta tag is a good pratice but for an auth token put it in a cookie is the right way. But it's just "style" norm i think. But i approve your answer because it works and without it, i'll spend my time to looking for a solution. Thx

Comment: I know they're different :) and you are right to use Cookies for this one. In my application I handle the Auth from Front End. It's because when somehow your server session is destroyed, you don't want to redirect your users to your spring page but rather handle it from the Angular application and if possible without disrupting the current URL (by a modal or so). 

Anyways, thanks for accepting the answer. Happy Coding!